# Calling chrome chooseEntry inside XmlHttpRequest readyState 4

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to save an image in fileSystem from my blob response but the file dialog is not showing, this is my script:

```
var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr2.open("GET", "http://website.org?url=http://www.google.com");
xhr2.responseType = "blob";
xhr2.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr2.readyState == 4) {
        console.log(xhr2.response); //Blob {type: "text/xml", size: 17830, slice: function}
        $('img')[0].src=window.URL.createObjectURL(xhr2.response); //response image is showing fine

        console.log($('#mydiv').attr('id')+'.jpg'); //suggestedName is 'web:file.html.jpg'
        chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({ type:'saveFile',suggestedName:$('#mydiv').text()+'.jpg',accepts:[{ extensions:['jpg'] }] },function(fileEntry){
        //chooseEntry is not creating file dialog
            console.log(fileEntry); //undefined
        });
    }
};
xhr2.send(null);
```

Manifest.json

```
"permissions": [
    "http://www.website.org",
    "syncFileSystem",
    {"fileSystem": ["write", "directory"]}
],
```

Comment: Please post your entire app or at least enough for another person to reproduce the issue you're seeing. We can't tell whether you're declaring the right permissions, properly structuring this item as a Chrome App, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it. Apparently the suggestedName value cannot have the character ':'

Comment: The [fileSystem API hope page](http://2-42-0.chrome-apps-doc.appspot.com/apps/fileSystem.html#method-chooseEntry) says at the top: "All failures are notified via chrome.runtime.lastError." Could you verify that this variable is appropriately set in this case? If it is not, then it's a bug that should be reported at http://crbug.com .

Comment: I'm sorry but dropped this project since i couldn't find a good service to convert a web page to an image. I completely forgot about that and will check next time I have a chance.